# Trigger of button is not working in behind code on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

There are 2 part for setting style of button.

The 1st is `BackgroundProperty` by `Style.Setters`. It's working well.

The 2nd is `BackgroundProperty` by `Style.Triggers` which is run by that Mouse is over a button. But, **It's not working**.

```
// the 1st BackgroundProperty by Style.Setters
Style style = new Style(typeof(Button));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, imageSourceOn));

// the 2nd BackgroundPropert by Style.Triggers
Setter setter = new Setter();
setter.Property = Button.BackgroundProperty;
setter.Value = imageSourceOff;
Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
trigger.Property = IsMouseOverProperty;
trigger.Value = true;
trigger.Setters.Add(setter);
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);

Button button = new Button();
button.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 80, 5);
button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
button.Name = name;
button.Click += handler;
button.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;

// setting Style
button.Style = style;
return button;
```

Comment: Why build it in code behind and not in resource dictionary of just on the xaml of the control or window?  The reason I ask is because "code behind xaml" sort of defeats the purpose of WPF

Comment: That trigger won't work because the Button's default ControlTemplate has its own trigger on IsMouseOver, which overrides the control's `Background` brush property. You'll have to edit a copy of the template if you really need to override that default behavior. Incidentally, Darkonekt is correct that you'd be much better off doing this type of thing in XAML.

Comment: @Darkonekt You are right. I should use the binding way with XAML. But, I just wanted to find the way to add and delete buttons dynamically which have each background image. Anyway, I found the way.

Comment: @yahocho you can also just bind the visibility of the buttons to a model property and have the same effect

Comment: @Darkonekt You are right. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ed Plunkett. 
I added `ControlTemplate` to override the control's `background` brush property.

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(Button));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, imageSourceOn));
```

This is the ControlTemplate part what I add:

```
ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));
FrameworkElementFactory elemFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
elemFactory.Name = "Border";
elemFactory.SetValue(Border.BackgroundProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(Button.BackgroundProperty));
template.VisualTree = elemFactory;
elemFactory.AppendChild(new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter)));
```

And, It is trigger part.

```
Setter setter = new Setter();
setter.Property = Button.BackgroundProperty;
setter.Value = imageSourceOff;
Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
trigger.Property = IsMouseOverProperty;
trigger.Value = true;
trigger.Setters.Add(setter);
```

Finally, I set my `ControlTemplate`.

```
template.Triggers.Add(trigger);
setter = new Setter();
setter.Property = Button.TemplateProperty;
setter.Value = template;
style.Setters.Add(setter);
```

It works well.